# Is there a way to detect which requests have been made using same connection in Apache log?

Tags: logging, apache2, port, tcpip

I use `mod_log_config` and `mod_log_forensic` to log all requests made to an Apache server.
Some of those requests use `Keep-Alive` and I would like to find out which requests have been made using the same connection.

Here is what I have for the moment (request for static files made from one client, by fetching a single page from browser) :

```
LogFormat "%t %h %{local}p %{remote}p \"%r\" %>s %k" customlog

[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 3
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:32 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 4
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 3
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 3
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 5
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 1
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 3
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 2
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 4
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 4
[30/Nov/2023:17:11:33 +0100] 127.0.0.1 443 52702 "GET ... HTTP/2.0" 200 6
```

`%k` is *Number of keepalive requests handled on this connection.*

I would like to group those requests together, by connection. Can I assume that requests made from same source IP / port IP (and same dest IP / port IP in this case) are requests made from the same connection ?

If yes, how to explain that `%k` parameter has duplicates ?
If it's same connection, I would expect all those numbers to be unique.